# How to send credit card form data to payment gateway without saving in database in magento?

Tags: php, magento

without saveing credit card cvv number in magento quote table and send this cvv number to payment gateway.(ICICI Moto payment gateway)

Comment: Magento doesn't save credit card information by default.  Why do you think it does?

Comment: Yes, for seamless (moto), we need to send cvv number with the api

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
In payment model, add two line and get it any where

```
 assignData($data){
    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $session->setData('cc_cid',$info->getCcCid());
 }
```